# ¿Es posible cambiar el ícono en un marcador cuando la pestaña está cerrada?

Tags: javascript, ajax, plugin, navegador-web

Es relativamente sencillo cambiar el ícono de la pestaña de nuestro sitio en el navegador. Si tenemos alguna función de Javascript adecuada, podemos lograr que el ícono se actualice con algún cambio de estado o de color, para atraer la atención del usuario, quien vendrá a nuestra pestaña para conocer las novedades.

Asimismo me estaba preguntando si es posible cambiar dinámicamente el ícono de un marcador (correspondiente a nuestro sitio), aún cuando el mismo no está abierto en ninguna de las pestañas.

¿Alguien sabe si esto es posible? ¿Debe ser hecho con algún enchufe (plugin) del navegador?

---

Una imágen para ilustrar la pregunta de Radames: suelo tener marcadores simples de ícono, tal como muestro aquí. Me pareció que puede ser útil que estos íconos (que son los mismos del favicon) se pudiesen actualizar en el background, aun con la pestaña cerrada.
[image: Captura de pantalla]

Comment: Que sentido tiene cambiar el icono del sitio si nadie puede verlo? ya que esta cerrada la pestaña?

Comment: Edité la pregunta agregando una imágen ilustrativa. Muchas gracias

Comment: En particular, he observado que el ícono de LinkedIn cambia de color cuando ese sitio adquiere notificaciones, pero siempre con la pestaña abierta